# Is the "registerSiteRoutes" hook screwing up my template path?

Tags: plugin-development, controller, routes

**This may be a bug...**

I have a controller action which has been working great. It's a simple action with a single purpose... load a template with an internal value.

```
public function actionMyAction()
{
    $this->renderTemplate('myplugin/_mytemplate', array(
        'internalVar' => craft()->myPlugin->internalVar
    ));
}
```

When I call that action via a simple URL, everything loads flawlessly:

> mywebsite.com/actions/myPlugin/myAction

**Here's where it gets interesting...**

So I just discovered the [registerSiteRoutes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerSiteRoutes) hook. It looks awesome, and would make accessing my special page that much easier for a front-end user!

Here's how I implemented it in my `MyPluginPlugin.php` file:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'myroute' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/myAction')
    );
}
```

**The good news is,** the route is properly followed, and my controller action gets loaded.

**The bad news is,** suddenly the template that's supposed to be loaded can't be found. :(

> **Template Error**
>
> Unable to find the template "myplugin/_mytemplate".

So does anyone know, **what's going on here?** I know that the `renderTemplate` method does some minor rewriting of the template path, but why would it be different when accessing via a front-end route?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Craft will only check for templates in your plugin’s templates/ folder during CP and action requests. When you start routing to your controller action via a site-facing route, it’s no longer either one of those; it’s just a normal Site request. So you will need to point Craft to your plugin’s templates folder explicitly.

```
// Point Craft to this plugin's templates/ folder
$templatesPath = craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'myplugin/templates/';
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($templatesPath);

// Render and output the template
$this->renderTemplate('_mytemplate', $variables);
```

Note that it will no longer be necessary to include your plugin’s handle in the template path.

Comment: Minor typo in your solution, it should apparently be `craft()->path->setTemplatesPath`... Other than that, it worked perfectly! Thanks Brandon!

Comment: Because I no longer need the plugin's handle in the template path, I also have to remove it from `extends` tags in the template. Which is fine, except when the layout I'm extending `extends` a layout from my main (non-plugin) templates. It now can't find that layout, because it's looking in my plugin templates.

Comment: @PhilGyford Yeah if you go this route, you can only include templates that live inside the directory passed into setTemplatesPath(). No way around that currently.